# Mean of certain column data in python

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Jt1K.png)

Hi guys, just wondering if I could get the mean of the "Tax" column for a certain "Year".
So for example: I would want to get the mean of the "Tax" for the "Year" 2020 and 1999.

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want the mean of the tax column for all years between 2020 and 1999 (1999, 2000, 2001, ..., 2020), or just for 1999 and 2020?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter rows and then calculate the mean, In this case we use [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) in order to filter:

```
df.loc[df['year'].isin([1999, 2000]), "Tax"].mean()
```

If you want calculate mean for each year:

```
df.groupby("year")["Tax"].mean().loc[[1999, 2000]]
```

Comment: works great, Thanks for the quick response!